# Как закрепить картинку, чтобы она не смещалась?

Tags: html, css

Как закрепить картинку, чтобы она не смещалась? На 2 скр. увеличил масштаб,а на 3 скр. уменьшил масштаб, 1 скр. не изменял вообще. Нужно, чтобы вот так смотрелось даже при увеличении масштаба или уменьшения.

Код такой:

```
style='position:fixed; right: 472px; top:42px; border:0 !important; opacity: 0.8; height: 16px !important; width: 27px !important;'
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rTM28/

Comment: Вот тут ищи где-то было все по фиксации в css может поможет [видео](https://rustvcom.com/info/)

Answer (score 1):

1. position:fixed -> position:absolute
2. родителю задать position:relative (если уже не задан absolute или fixed)
3. откалибровать положение картинки